# Using Facebook Graph API to automatically delete comments in a group

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to automatically delete certain comments on posts within a facebook group which I admin.

When I try and delete it, I get this:

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#3) Publishing comments through the API is
only available for page access tokens
```

I happen to have a page which I have a page access token for. When I use it I get:

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: Unsupported delete request. Object with ID
'722227087901405' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing
permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the
Graph API documentation at
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
```

I've set every permission possible and have also tried to see if it's possible to get a page access token for the group I admin to no avail.

Is what I'm trying to do possible or just not supported?

Also I don't know how much it matters but I'm doing this with the python SDK.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: please use relevant tags only, since you are using python it´s not neccessary to tag javascript and php too.

Comment: No, this is not possible. You can not use a page access token to do anything with the group, or its contents.